# when to use java.lang.reflect package

Tags: java, reflection

This might be a simple question,

I did not get a chance to use `java.lang.reflect` package and its associated classes. 
But I know the Java compiler uses reflection to get the class information.

My question is why the reflection package has been exposed by Java when it's used by the compiler itself? Could any one shed light on situations we use reflect package?

Comment: Any time you want to use reflection.

Comment: One sample use is annotation processing. But if you ask this question, you very probably don't have a user for it yourself ;)

Comment: No, the compiler does _not_ use reflection to get the class information.

Comment: Exactly in real time when do we use? @DaveNewton

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: @MaheshVarma Tooling, framework functionality, expression languages, work-arounds, to name a few.

Comment: I read somewhere that package is used in testing phase

Comment: @MattBall are you sure the compiler does not use??

Comment: @MaheshVarma Reflection would tell the compiler about the classes it is using. It needs to know about the classes the program it is compiling will be using.

Comment: @MaheshVarma It is also used for Introspection. Take a look at classes java.beans.Introspector and java.beans.PropertyDescriptor. It helps you to get all getters and setters on your class attributes (which are called "properties" in introspection terminology) and skip others methods.

Comment: Can anyone tell why the question is closed ? @MattBall  Isnt it a real question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly, whenever you want to introspect on classes and determine their structure, invoke methods by name (String) etc.

Lots of frameworks will use this.

e.g. if you nominate properties in a Spring config (XML) file, it will take that string (e.g. "position"), derive a method name (e.g. "setPosition") and then invoke that. Note that in this case you've started from a string, and derived/called the method at *runtime*. The compiler hasn't been involved at all.

Comment: Internally, the compiler searches in the method area for the mapping. doesn't it ? @Brian Agnew

Comment: @Brian Are you mixing Introspection and Reflexion? Getting the "write" method from a property name is made via java.beans.PropertyDescriptor#getWriteMethod(). It is probably based on reflection but it is not part of java.lang.reflect package.

Comment: @adenoyelle - reflection will be used at the core to get the class method names

Answer (score 1):

Wow interesting  - I just read about this in ["Core Java 2"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FCore-Java-Volume-Fundamentals-Edition%2Fdp%2F0130471771&ei=xw2uUYvJCITc8ASelYCoDA&usg=AFQjCNFFqrvpVMqVZcA69Hw6u9qwjJvfQQ&sig2=EA0RqzJxtWJeodh-5VygGQ) (Horstmann, Ch 5 - inheritance) :

> The reflection library gives you a a very rich and elaborate toolset
>   to write programs that manipulate Java code dynamically. ... heavily
>   used in JavaBeans, the component architecture for Java.. Using
>   reflection, Java can support tools like the ones to which users of
>   Visual Basic have grown accustomed.

Overall, it's a rather powerful feature. See more at the [API page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use metaprograming with that feature, is extremely powerfull, and costly too, with no mention of it's difficulty. but there are cases in that feature become great help.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming

Answer (score 0):

In the old days we would write a program like this:

- Write/Modify the class, methods, etc
- Compile it
- Run it

but now with reflection:

- Write/Modify the class, methods, etc

  - Compile it
  - Run it
  - Modify the class even after compiling and running !

  if you are interested please try the link I have provided as a source
  below. Hope this

  helps and good question.

source [University of Washington](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse142/12su/exploreFiles/reflection/reflection.pdf)

Comment: That appears to be a link to a presentation on ray tracing. How would you modify a class method at runtime using reflection? I thought compilation was handled via the compilation api?

Comment: @DaveNewton correct, it's a link to presentation which has more details about java reflection and when to use it.

Comment: Good lord, no it doesn't. Just because the word "reflection" appears in a presentation about *ray tracing*, which is all about **one type** of reflection, doesn't mean it's about Java reflection. You didn't even look at it.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh my gosh you are being very peaky now :)  !! I was just trying to share some information.

Comment: Why share information about ray tracing in a question about Java reflection?! Or wrong information about what the reflection API allows?

Comment: are you sure because the power point I shared it was about java reflection ? what would you like me to do at this point ?

Comment: The presentation, called "traceHelpSession_13sp.ppt", with a title page "Ray Tracer, Spring 2013 Help Session", isn't about Java reflection at all. Perhaps you posted the wrong link. I'd like you to post the correct link and remove the stuff about the reflection API that isn't true, or provide more information showing how it *is* true, because AFAIK the reflection API doesn't let you compile, run, or modify classes--just *reflect* on them.

Comment: oh you are correct....not sure how that happened ...sorry and good catch. I'll update it now.

Comment: ok I added the correct link. Let me know if there is anything else you'd like me to change. thanks for your help.